# beamer: how to label an equation with \alert in its \tag?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, highlighting

I would like to `\alert` an equation tag, then refer to it in another overlay.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \only<1>{
      My equation reads:
      \[
        a=0.
        \tag{\alert{Eq. 1}}
        %\label{eq1}
      \]
    }
    \only<2>{
      As stated in \eqref{eq1}, $a=0$.
    }
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

however, upon cutting the percent sign, the latex complains that:

```
! Argument of \beamerx@\alert has an extra }.
```

of course, using a plain tag does work even if labeled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the first error message for me is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@sort #1#2->\long \def \beamer@todo 
                                           {#1}\def \beamer@ospec {}\beamer@...
```

In any case, it works if you `\protect` the `\alert`:

```
\tag{\protect\alert{Eq. 1}}
```

However, note that this will only color the tag text, not the parentheses, and it will also color any reference.

Comment: if you use `\tag*`, put parentheses around "Eq. 1", and use just `\ref` instead of `\eqref`, the parentheses will also be colored, both with the equation and in the reference.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I only want my text colored, not the parentheses, so the \protect is just enough!